# A result preempted by XYZ in 2003

Tags: conference

I was attending a conference recently where one of the presenters had put it in their  title slide, "**this work is preempted by XYZ in 2003**". What does this exactly mean? I didn't see this in any other presentation. Are they talking about some conflicts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might ask the presenter, actually, but I would read it as follows:

This work was done independently but repeats work that was actually done previously in 2003 by XYZ.

It is possible that no one noticed the early work, the paper was accepted by reviewers, but prior to the conference the authors learned of the earlier work and want to be completely honest about it. But they decided (along with the committee) that it was fine to do the presentation.

This sort of thing happens, though the review process tries to make it rare. But some works are fairly obscure.

Comment: I went ahead and emailed the authors. They are saying, the results were published with some other name(terminology) and they missed the literature. It also escaped the reviewers knowledge and it was figured out 1 week before the conference.